# Prove directly that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+} \exists y \in \mathbb{R^-}: y^2 = x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I want to prove directly that the following statement is correct:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+} \exists y \in \mathbb{R^-}: y^2 = x$$

By having a plain look I can say that it is true. However, what is hard for me is the formal prove of this statement.

I tried:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R^-}$

Then $-y ^2$ is in $\mathbb{R^+}$. Therefore, the statement is true!

Is this a correct direct proof. I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: How are you defining multiplication in $\Bbb R$? Or at least squaring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nono at first $-y^2$ is still in $\mathbb{R}^-$.

The second point is you don't have to show that the square of a negative number is positive, but you have to show that every positive number is the square of a negative one.

Furthermore given the existence of a root function which maps every $x$ to it's square root you have:

$$y^2=x\iff y^2-x=0$$

and via the third binomial theorem you have

$$y^2-x=(y-\sqrt{x})\cdot (y+\sqrt{x})$$

So you just have to check that there is a $y\in \mathbb{R}^-$ such that 
$$y+ \sqrt{x}=0$$

Comment: If $\sqrt x$ is defined, by it's very definition $y=-\sqrt x$ will work immediately.

Comment: Third binomial theorem?

Comment: @Alraxite $(a+b)\cdot (a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I mean, I've never heard of it. Is it really called the third binomial theorem?

Comment: @GitGud for sure, but do you think they should show that $\sqrt{x}$ is well defined? We did use Banachs Fix point theorem for that if I remember correct

Comment: @Alraxite [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=%22Third+binomial+theorem%22) is your friend. Doesn't look standard.

Comment: @Alraxite well maybe the third binomial formula is a better translation

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I think the question is lacking a lot of foundational context and can't really be answered as it is.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Okay, but why the *third*? Sorry to drag on, I'm just curious.

Comment: @Alraxite well because the first one is $(a+b)^2= a^2+2ab+b^2$ and the second is $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab-b^2$ and the third is $(a+b)\cdot (a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Um, okay.